# Is this good practice? Joining two objects after subdivision

Tags: modeling, mesh

I would like to know if this is good practice in joining two objects (in my case a sword pommel with a handgrip).

The handgrip has a shade smooth and the pommel has a mirror and subdivision modifier.

**Am I doing good to stretch the Pommel's mesh till it joins well with the handgrip (it appears correct when I switch to object mode)?**

**Is this correct practice, keeping in mind that I want to make all objects forming the sword a single object in the future?**

I am asking to avoid possible future errors.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly reasonable, actually, desirable, to model mechanically separate parts of an object as separate parts of your mesh. So the junction between the steel section and the ridged handgrip would be fine as separate mesh sections. Even so, in this case, I would probably duplicate the lower end of the top section and use the duplicate as the upper end of the bottom section, if I wanted a match.

If you're looking to reproduce your reference, though, there will need to be continuity of shading and texture over the junction *within* the steel section as it shows in your model. In other words, the meshes will need to be merged at some point, or at least have exactly matching normals where the two parts meet.

In order to achieve that, the **underlying** topology of the two halves must match, vertex-for-vertex, **before the effect of any modifiers,** unless you want to commit yourself to a ton of work.

Slightly beside this point, it's often possible for subdivision to 'rescue' a mesh. The un-subdivided mesh can be tortured, stretching in a way  wildly dissimilar from the final object, and yet produce reasonable-looking curvatures when subdivided. This will almost always cause trouble, and create work. In those cases, there is always a better basic mesh.

Comment: It looks as if @Jachym has made a very nice 'continuous' solution.

Comment: Thanks, both Jachym and Robin.  Jachym gave me a good way to know what the best parctice would be depending on the project but you Robin gave me the sure way I want to proceed.  That being of first joining the two meshes, vertice by vertice and the apply the modifiers this because I want it to be seamless as the references.  The project I am working on is the blade Anduril from the Lord of the Rings trilogy and people will be LOOKING at each minute detail.

Answer (score 5):

> There isn't one right way, use what works best for you :)

- You can either join objects into one object (<kbd>CTRL+J</kbd>) consisting of multiple meshes
- Or even join into one mesh, with all vertices manually connected (seamless)

[image]

**Example**
This sword is one *object* consisting of multiple *meshes*

- Easy to swap different parts
- It resembles a real sword structure which adds to realism

[image]

[image]