# How to model nails on the end of fingers?

Tags: modeling

I have base mesh of a hand and want to model nails on it. I extrude and shape the nails but fail to get the look of nails.

[image]

[image]

I tried extruding but it's not looking natural:

[image]

Any suggestion of how I can do it better?

Comment: You could just use separate meshes a the nails

Comment: Hello :). As @SomeGuy mentioned, separate meshes would probably work best. Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/160367/

Answer (score 0):

You should create a loop cut along the edge of the finger and extrude from there, so that the nail extrudes outwards instead of upwards.