# Should objects added in edit mode be merged together or can they exist as separate objects?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

Are unlinked mesh islands of the same object considered bad modeling? And, when should I merge meshes and when should I keep them separate?

Comment: generally what is considered as one object in real world will be one object in blender, but it's not always true, it may be more convenient to keep objects separate, when for example they have their own modifier, in that case you can parent all the parts to the main part, or to an empty, so that it's easy to move in the scene.

Comment: Related: [What are the benefits of modeling in one piece, or as separate parts?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14482/78972), [Is this good practice? Joining two objects after subdivision](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/160432/78972)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it depends.  If you want to add meshes in edit mode, they'll be added to your current object.  Sometimes this is what you want, sometimes not.  A mesh added in edit mode will also share any materials and object data of the original object.

Also note that your Add options are different depending if you are in Object vs Edit mode.